# No Swipe TouchGesture in touchEvent?

Tags: swipe, blackberry-storm

I didn't find any similar posts when searching previous questions.

I am developing a game in MIDP for Blackberry Storms.  I am using a `BlackBerryGameCanvas` and using the callback function `touchEvent`.  As an argument, I'm getting an instance of `TouchEvent` But I want to listen for a `TouchGesture` like `Swipe`.  But after doing swipe in simulator touch screen I am getting null as result:

```
public void touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
    TouchGesturenow = message.getGesture();

    //always getting null as a result

    //according to API when user does not perform any gesture 
    //operation then it would return null otherwise reference 
    //but here I have performed a swipe gesture then also it is returning null.

}
```

If it is not possible at all then I have to use

`getMovePoints(int touch, int[] x, int[] y, int[] time)` ..and some calculation .

Can anybody confirm for me: does Swipe TouchGesture not work with Blackberry Storm?

Answer (score 0):

Per answer in other SO discussion, simulation of swipe gestures for BB Storm seems to be quite complicated: [Blackberry Storm Emulator - TouchGesture events not firing, how to get a Swipe to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173044/blackberry-storm-emulator-touchgesture-events-not-firing-how-to-get-a-swipe-to).

Most likely reason for getting `null` (meaning "this event is not a gesture" per BlackBerry API) is that you just didn't do *swipe in simulator touch screen* well enough for emulator to recognize it as swipe.

---

> I am developing a game in MIDP for Blackberry Storms.

For the sake of precision - `TouchGesture` has nothing to do with MIDP - there's simply no such thing in MIDP 2 [API](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html). Nor there is `touchEvent` in MIDP API.

All the API and features you use appear BlackBerry-specific: [BlackBerryGameCanvas](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/lcdui/game/BlackBerryGameCanvas.html), [TouchEvent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/TouchEvent.html) etc. Again, this issue in general has nothing to do with MIDP .